# PHP write new PHP file with header includes and jquerys?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hy Guys i tried to write with php an other php file but always fail...
Is it possible to do it like my snippet?
Thanks in advance.

```html
$newfile = fopen("file.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<html>\n
<title>my php file written with php</title>\n
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">\n
include 'header.php'\n
<BR><BR><BR><BR>\n
This is the php file written by a php page.\n\n
Here is a link: <a HREF='index.html'>home</a>.\n
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.option-btn', function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('open');
 $('.control-center').toggleClass('open');
});
</script>\n
</body>\n
</html>";
fwrite($newfile, $txt);
fclose($newfile);
```

Comment: What error shops up, when it "fails"?

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 :/

Comment: Check your server logs for an error message

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'css' (T_STRING) in /home/add.php on line 38

Comment: Also better is to wrap whole string in single quot and use concatenation where ever some variable needs to be translate. Because if string is in double quot then variables cab be translated. But if string is in single quot then it will be printed as it is. like $text = ' some html etc '.$somephpvariable.' remaining html and javascript etc';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to put a double quoted string in a double quoted string, hence your error.

In this line

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">\n
```

And in this line, you missed a `;` although that is not causing the error.

```
 include 'header.php';\n
```

And if you want to run an include, it needs to be wrapped in `<?php ... ?>`

And you missed the `<head>` tag and the `<body>` tag and the `<script>` should go in the `<head>` section.

Amended code

```
$newfile = fopen("file.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<html>\n
<head>
<title>my php file written with php</title>\n
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>\n
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.option-btn', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.control-center').toggleClass('open');
});
</script>\n
</head>\n
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<body>
<BR><BR><BR><BR>\n
This is the php file written by a php page.\n\n
Here is a link: <a HREF='index.html'>home</a>.\n

</body>\n
</html>";
fwrite($newfile, $txt);
fclose($newfile);
```